# Is it possibly to compare two different arrays against each other?

Tags: arrays, assembly, mips

Lets say you have array A = ['1','1','1'] and array B = ['1','1','0']; How can you compare the elements of the arrays against each other in MIPS Assembly?

**Here's an example of code:**

```
# syscall codes
PRINT_STRING = 4

    .data
    .align  2

ArrayA:
    .word   1, 1, 1

ArrayB: 
    .word   1, 1, 0

true:
    .asciiz "True!"
false:
    .asciiz "False!"

    .text
    .align  2

# Compares the two Arrays
main:
    la  $t0, ArrayA     # Loads the address of ArrayA into t0
    la  $t1, ArrayB     # Loads the address of ArrayB into t1

    beq $t0, $t1, T     # If ArrayA == ArrayB; then goto T
    bne $t0, $t1, F     # If ArrayA != ArrayB; then goto F


T:
    li  $v0, PRINT_STRING   # Prints True
    la  $a0, true       
    syscall

F:
    li  $v0, PRINT_STRING   # Prints False
    la  $a0, false       
    syscall
```

**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: By loading values from the corresponding addresses, then doing `beq`, `slt`, `sub` or whatever you want.

Comment: @Michael But is there a more efficient way to do this if i have 1 main array and comparing the main array to 8 other arrays?

Comment: comparing the main against each of the 8 arrays (1 array at time) is probably best to cache lines... hard to say with 3 value arrays, that's too short for anything sophisticated, simple hardcoded test of 3 values will be very likely fastest. Anything more sophisticated needs particular kind of data, for example for long substrings search it is better to compare from last char and have prebuild table with maximal possible advance of offset in case of mismatch, but for general data you have to compare them, and reading them one by one (in order as in stored in memory) is what CPU does at best.